# Не создается база данных при codefirst Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Пишу проект используя Identity, 
Контекст:

```
public class Context: IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public Context():base("DefaultConnection") { }

        public static Context Create()
        {
            return new Context();
        }
    }
```

ConnectionString:
...

...
но при запуске получаю следующую ошибку:
При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Произошла ошибка Local Database Runtime.Указанный экземпляр LocalDB не существует.
Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь проверьте, запущен ли у вас sql сервер. Затем посмотрите, правильно ли вы указали его имя в connection string. Если используете localdb, проверьте, какая у вас версия. И покажите свою строку подключения.